# Can __FILE__ and __LINE__ be made linkable when printed to Qt Creator's debug console?

Tags: debugging, qt, gdb, qt-creator, c-preprocessor

**Header:**

```
#define TRACE_ERROR(s)                      \
{
  ...
  char TraceBuffer[512];
  sprintf(TraceBuffer, "%s\t(%s:%d)", s, __FILE__, __LINE__);
  DebugErrTrace(TraceBuffer);
  ...
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
void DebugErrTrace(char *String, ...) {
  ...
  qDebug() << String;
}
```

The above spits out a line of debug trace, which might look something like

`ERROR File Missing! (..\trunk\Common\FileManager.cpp:102)`

in Qt Creator's debug console.

I've noticed that Qt's own error messages e.g.

`Object::connect: No such slot cClass::Method(QString) in ..\trunk\Components\Class.cpp:301`

create what looks like a hyperlink around the `__FILE__:__LINE__` part of the debug line, linking to the line which caused the problem. Is there any way I can I do this with my own debug output?

Cheers, Sam

Comment: Have you tried making the tab into a space, or removing the parentheses around the file/line pair in the output? Maybe Qt Creator is using some other method of outputting its messages?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I hadn't thought to try that, but it didn't work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Stepping into QObject::connect() shows that Qt's debug message is generated with qWarning (see QObject:err_method_notfound() in Qt.4.7.4). However, using a similar `qWarning("Test in %s:%i", __FILE__, __LINE__ );` doesn't give me a linked message either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Qt Creator source code ([there](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/src/plugins/qtsupport/qtoutputformatter.cpp#line47)), the hyperlinks are only created for lines matching these regular expressions:

```
"^(?:\\[Qt Message\\] )?(file:///.+:\\d+(?::\\d+)?):"
"Object::.*in (.*:\\d+)"
"ASSERT: .* in file (.+, line \\d+)"
"^   Loc: \\[(.*)\\]"
```

So the simplest lines you could construct look like this:

```
qWarning("file:///%s:%i: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, "your message");
qWarning("   Loc: [%s:%i] %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, "your message");
```

Qt Creator doesn't seem to care if the path after `"file:///"` is absolute or not.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to alexisdm's answer (which helped me very much, big thanks!):

Instead of defining a custom macro, I would suggest to do the following in newer versions of Qt and use `qDebug` itself:

```
qSetMessagePattern("%{if-category}%{category}: %{endif}%{message}\n   Loc: [%{file}:%{line}]");
```

The part before `\n` is Qt's default message pattern, and splitting with `\n` has the benefit that the log messages also can contain characters like `[` or `]` without messing up the links.

The message pattern can easily be extended with other log details like timestamps, thread id and so on, see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#warning-and-debugging-messages). When adding other details, keep the link in a seperate line to avoid issues with Qt Creator's parsing.