# Display link to code in Qt creator output pane

Tags: hyperlink, output, qt-creator

When running QTest in Qt Creator with terminal setting disabled, the output pane display links to the test line failing, ie:

```
FAIL!  : MidiTest::testMTCWriter() Compared values are not the same
    Actual   (tcCount): 1
    Expected (2)      : 2
    Loc: [../../Joker/tests/AutoTest/MidiTest.cpp(271)]
```

Is it possible to make such link? For example I configured doxygen as an external tool and I'd like to produce the same output for documentation errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can \_\_FILE\_\_ and \_\_LINE\_\_ be made linkable when printed to Qt Creator's debug console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916267/can-file-and-line-be-made-linkable-when-printed-to-qt-creators-debug-co)